# Do I need to sanitize results from database query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Our application in PHP / MySQL uses PDO prepared statements to insert data from user without any sanitizing. In the later stage user can copy created entries, thousand at the time.

For copying part we have tested:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO files (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$pdo->beginTransaction();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
$pdo->commit();
```

vs

```
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO files (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES . implode(', ', $loop_query));
```

$row represent rows from database.
First one is 3 times slower than second. We would like to implement second approach.

How safe is using data from database without prepared statements?

Comment: involving users NOT AT ALL SAFE !

Comment: Can you tell us what is there inside your `$loop_query` ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran it is answered in the question and doesn't matter even a little.

Comment: Punished with a down vote for a question? What is the purpose of SO then??

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe. As you mention, data on DB is raw.

If you retrieve it to the programming language (php in this case) and use again in a sql sentence it must be protected again against sql injecton.

can't you do a `insert (fields) select values` instead?

Comment: Nope, because data needs to be updated before insert

Comment: well, in that case applies first part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe at all. Entirely.